# Get Criteria Values from a filter - Script GApp

Tags: google-apps-script

I've sorted my spreadsheet. Now, using a script, I would like to get all the criteria values of one specific filtered columns.

Let's say my columns is as following:

400
400
401
403

Basically, filter's criteria will be : 400, 401, 403.

Then I would like to get this values (400, 401, 403)and use them.

Any ideas ?

Comment: did you filter them in the spreadsheet or in the script? Or do you want to filter them? what do you want to do with them, do you want the range of the values? What have you tried already?

Comment: Hi, 

I've already filtered them in the Spreadsheet. But can also be done using the script if it's easier.

I want to get all the criteria values. Basically, when you click on your filter using spreadsheet, you can select "Filter by values". I want to get all these values you can select. 

I've tryed different code of "getvalues", and a solution given in Stackoverflow using Filterbuilder (doesnt seem to work).